# Which is more performant: creating 1000+ DAGs or 1 DAG w/ 1000+ tasks?

Tags: airflow

I have an Apache Airflow DAG that fetches data for a stock symbol and loads it into a datalake. There are thousands of stock symbols.

Right now I'm using templating to create a DAG for each stock symbol. I'm wondering if it would be more performant to create a single DAG and have thousands of tasks instead.

I tried having a single DAG and multiple tasks with just 500 stock symbols, and the Airflow UI started becoming unresponsive to load the graph view (FYI, my work machine has 64GB of memory).

If one workflow for thousands of symbols creates 1000+ DAGS or tasks, I really need to follow the most scalable practice as more workflows will be added in the future.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would opt for one DAG with all tasks. To improve UI experience you can group them into task groups (in Airflow 2.0) by 10/20 or what seems to be feasible. Having one dag per symbol doesn't sounds maintainable but from performance perspective in 2.0 this should not impact scheduling so much.

Comment: task groups is the way to go. Thanks for this. If you elevate your comment to an answer I will approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve UI experience you can group task into [task groups](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/task-groups) (in Airflow 2.0) by 10/20 or what seems to be feasible. Having one dag per symbol doesn't sounds maintainable but from performance perspective in 2.0 this should not impact scheduling so much.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to logically separate the tasks for each symbol, I think it will be good to modify your current operator to accept a list of symbols and use some concurrency in the operator to speed up. In this way, it will be easy and manageable in future because you can decide on how many worker jobs needs to spin up to finish the pipeline without causing a major load on UI to visualize all the tasks.

Comment: While it may work it is not best pattern because in case of failure, when you rerun the task you will ingest all the data once more. It's recommended to keep tasks in Airflow as atomic as possible.